# Performance issue migrating spring boot 2.1.1 with java 8 to spring boot 3.0.2 with java 17

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications, java-17

No Performance issue with java 8 with spring boot 2.1.1 but getting performance issue in java 17 with spring boot 3.0.2 please help me what's the happening here

here is the code below using to get data from database

```java
public Iterable<DTO> findById(Integer id, MultiValueMap<String, String> filterParams, Pageable pageable) throws Exception {
    Page<MODEL> list= repo.findAll(Specification.doFilter(id, filterParams), pageable);
    List<DTO> casDto = list.stream().map(xref -> DtoMapper.convertDto(xref.getContact(), campaignId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new PageImpl<>(casContactsDto, pageable, casprContactCampaignRefList.getTotalElements());
}
```

Below is the specifications code

```java
public static Specification<MODEL> doFilter(Integer campaignId, MultiValueMap<String, String> filterParams) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        return Specification.where(isActiveInCampaign(campaignId))
            .and(hasNumTouches(filterParams.get("number_of_touches")))
            .and(hasPrivacyRules(filterParams.get("privacy_rules")))
            .and(hasContactValue(filterParams.get("wksp_contact"), "fullName"))
            .and(hasContactValue(filterParams.get("wksp_account"), "companyName"))
            .and(hasContactValue(filterParams.get("wksp_primary_ae"), "primaryAE"))
            .and(hasContactValue(filterParams.get("wksp_email_address"), "emailAddress"))
            .toPredicate(root, query, cb);
    };
}
```

Comment: Try to enable logging of generated SQL queries and compare them, probably that will give you a hint

Comment: i See lot of queries firing with java 17 upgrade with spring boot 3.0.2